Valid and Invalid Proofs Regarding $(I - uv^T)^{-1} = I + \alpha u v^{T}$
I have been working through a linear algebra problem, and I have some doubts on how to correctly write the proof. The first part of the problem is to show that for $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if $I - uv^{T}$ is invertible, then there exists $\alpha$ such that $(I - uv^{T})^{-1} = I + \alpha uv^{T}$.
To find $\alpha$, we suppose $(I - uv^{T})^{-1} = I + \alpha uv^{T}$, and by calculating $\alpha$ from$(I - uv^{T})(I + \alpha uv^{T}) = I$, we can conclude $\alpha = \frac{1}{1-v^{T}u}$. So we should have $v^{T}u \neq 1$ so that $I + \alpha uv^{T}$ is the inverse, but what if this inequality doesn't hold?
In the second part, we are asked to prove $I - uv^{T}$ is invertible iff $v^{T}u \neq 1$.
If $v^{T}u \neq 1$, $\alpha \neq 0$ but we cannot infer $I - uv^{T}$ is invertible just because $\alpha \neq 0$, since in the first part we supposed that $I - uv^{T}$ is invertible and then we derived $\alpha$.
However, if $I - uv^{T}$ is invertible, then we can conclude $v^{T}u \neq 1$ supposing $I + \alpha uv^{T}$ is the inverse, but what if it's not?
So I think should solve the second part independently from the first, maybe using Matrix determinant lemma? Is my reasoning correct, and is there any other solutions?

Note that $(I-uv^T)u=u-u(v^Tu)=(1-v^Tu)u$.
Hence $u$ is an eigenvector of $I-uv^T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1-v^Tu$. Now, if $I-uv^T$ is invertible, all of its eigenvalues, including $1-v^Tu$, must be nonzero. Conversely, if $1-v^Tu\ne0$, then as you have already shown, $I-uv^T$ has an inverse $I+\frac{uv^T}{1-v^Tu}$.

Thanks for the response. But the $u$ is not necessarily non-zero, so it may not be an eigenvector.

@MrAmbiguneDL That is only a corner case. If $u=0$, clearly $I-uv^T=I$ is invertible and its inverse is equal to $I+\frac{1}{1-v^Tu}uv^T=I$.

Oh, that's right! Thanks, that solves it. @user1551
